# Square bitmap before uploading

Tags: java, android, image-processing

hello i have the following code for getting image from gallery activity and i want the image to be squared to particular dimension say 400*400 before it is uploaded while maintaining its aspect ratio so that all uploaded images be the same size. any ideas please

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        // When an Image is picked
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            assert selectedImage != null;
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            assert cursor != null;
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            imgPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            ImageView imgView = findViewById(R.id.imagebutton);
            int width = imgView.getWidth();
            int height = imgView.getHeight();
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath),width, height, false);
            imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            // Get the Image's file name
            String fileNameSegments[] = imgPath.split("/");
            fileName = fileNameSegments[fileNameSegments.length - 1];
            // Put file name in Async Http Post Param which will used in Php web app
            params.put("filename", fileName);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.noimageselected,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.erroroccurred, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
}

@Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = null;
            options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 3;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath, options);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            // Must compress the Image to reduce image size to make upload easy
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, stream);
            byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
            // Encode Image to String
            encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, 0);
            return "";
        }
```

Comment: thats all new to me I won't be able to implement that

Comment: you used src and dst what do they represent

Comment: it's a great pointer I'm still going through it

Comment: I can't really wrap my head around that so I'm going with a cropping tool to crop all images to a particular size before uploading

Answer (score 1):

Add this code for resize your image before uploading image

```
int newWidth=400; 
int newHeight=400;      
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap , newWidth, newHeight, true);

@Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = null;
        options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 3;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath, options);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        // Must compress the Image to reduce image size to make upload easy


        //Add these lines
        int newWidth=400; 
        int newHeight=400;      
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap , newWidth, newHeight, true);

        resizedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, stream);
        byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
        // Encode Image to String
        encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, 0);
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: that doesn't preserve the aspect ratio does it?

Comment: You can implemented by `int size=400;      
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap , size, size, true);`

Comment: you can also use `Bitmap resizedBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);`

Comment: still won't preserve aspect ratio because int size is passed as both width and height hence stretching of smaller images and pressing of larger ones

Comment: are you want to crop original image for square image?                                    If not then image is stretch obviously when image convert into square format...

Comment: For resize image in aspect ration in pixel  `public static Bitmap scaleDown(Bitmap realImage, float maxImageSize) {
        float ratio = Math.min(
                maxImageSize / realImage.getWidth(),
                maxImageSize / realImage.getHeight());
        int width = Math.round(ratio * realImage.getWidth());
        int height = Math.round(ratio * realImage.getHeight());

        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(realImage, width, height, true);
    }` maxImageSize in pixel